# How do I concatenate a string in a while loop?

Tags: ruby

I want to read some lines in a loop and concatenate them:

```
d = ""
while s = gets do
  d = d.concat(s)
end
puts d
```

After I cancel the loop with <kbd>CNTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (on Windows), the output is just the last string that I read in my loop. I tried it also with `+` and `<<` but with same result.

Comment: You only need `d.concat(s)`. It is a destructive method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in <s>two ways</s> this way:

```
d = ""
while s = gets do
  d << s
end
puts d
```

Edit: Marc-André Lafortune noticed using `+=` is not very good idea, so I leave only `<<` method here.

Comment: If you can modify the string in-place, `<<` seems to perform a lot better since it doesn't create a new string each time. Using `+=` should be reserved for cases when the initial string needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Two good ways are to either use `<<` or `join`:

```
d = ""
while s = gets do
  d << s
end
puts d
```

Or

```
a = []
while s = gets do
  a << s
end
puts a.join
```

What you **don't want to do** is use `+=` in the first example. Imagine your loop iterates 200 times and returns a 100 character-long `s`. You will build 200 strings, of lengths 100, 200, 300, ..., 199900, 200000. That will be `O(n^2)`.